# jQuery change() event doesn't fire when initial value is reselected

Tags: jquery

I've bound the jQuery change event to a select box like so:

```
$("#select_box").live('change', function() {
    selectFunction();
});
```

I'd like to have selectFunction() run every time a new value is selected.  Let's say the initial value of the select box is 0.  Then a user selects option 1 : change() event fires successfully.  But if the user then reselected the initial value of 0, the change() event won't fire.  It seems the change event fires on 'change from initial' instead of 'change from previous value' as I'd like.

Is there a good way to do what I'd like?

Comment: What browser are you using? And have you tried it in a different browser?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/YNmXV/

Comment: same http://jsfiddle.net/XBDhR/

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not sure what was going wrong. Now it seems to be working.  I had reloaded the page a number of times in Chrome earlier and it wasn't working as desired.